# Trying to iterate over specific column in python array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries in an array format.
Initially I would like the first row and column to have

```
{'score' : 0, 'pointer' : 'none'}
```

in each cell, however my for loops do not seem to be carrying this out.
Here is what I have so far:

```
mymatrix = [[0 for x in range(len(seq1)+1)]for x in range(len(seq2)+1)]

mymatrix[0][0] = {'score' : 0, 'pointer' : 'none'}

for x in mymatrix[0][:]:
    x = {'score' : 0, 'pointer' : 'none'}
for y in mymatrix[:][0]:
    y = {'score' : 0, 'pointer' : 'none'}

for row in mymatrix:
    print row
```

Where seq1 and seq2 are strings.

Comment: what are seq1 and seq2?

Comment: seq1 and seq2 are strings which are entered using raw_input, I need the number of columns and number of rows to be one more than the length of seq1 and seq2 respectively.

Comment: show some example input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already wrote two for loops in your list comprehension, you can just reuse them.

(I modified your list comprehension, I used `y` and `x` instead of 2 `x`)

```
seq1 = 'asdfasdfasdf'
seq2 = 'asdfasdfasdf'

mymatrix = [[0 for y in range(len(seq1)+1)]for x in range(len(seq2)+1)]
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ reuse this


d = {'score' : 0, 'pointer' : 'none'}

for y in range(len(seq1)+1):
    mymatrix[0][y] = d.copy()

# The first one is already covered, just leave it off using slice
for x in range(len(seq2)+1)[1:]:
    mymatrix[x][0] = d.copy()

for line in mymatrix:
    print(line)
```

Out:

```
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, {'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{'pointer': 'none', 'score': 0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem is here:

```
x = {'score' : 0, 'pointer' : 'none'}
```

This line of code isn't going to mutate the actual matrix. All you're doing here is reassigning the value of the name `x`, which is not inherently bound to the matrix you're trying to change. You need to directly reference the matrix. Try this instead:

```
for xind, x in enumerate(mymatrix[0][:]):
  mymatrix[0][xind] = {'score' : 0, 'pointer' : 'none'}
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: That's a bizarre error. enumerate returns integers specifically for that purpose. Make sure you're using xind and not x.

Comment: Definitely using xind and not x. Is enumerate from numpy or something?

Comment: Not that I know of, it should be built in. I didn't have to import anything to get it working.